# langchain: logprobs, best_of and echo parameters are not available on gpt-35-turbo model

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am trying to use langchain with gpt-35-turbo.
It seems that the new gpt3.5 turbo is not using certain parameters anymore as per the link [Learn how to work with the ChatGPT and GPT-4 models (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/chatgpt?pivots=programming-language-chat-completions)

> The following parameters aren't available with the new ChatGPT and GPT-4 models: `logprobs`, `best_of`, and `echo`. If you set any of these parameters, you'll get an error.

Now each time I initialise an LLM model through langchain with gpt-3.5-turbo, it gives me this error:

```
InvalidRequestError: logprobs, best_of and echo parameters are not available on gpt-35-turbo model. Please remove the parameter and try again. For more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2227346.
```

I don't know how to 'unset' these parameters in langchain.

This is my code:

```py
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate

llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, engine=deployment_name)

template = """
You are a helpful assistant that translates English to French. Translate this sentence from English to French: {text}
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["text"], template=template)
llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
response = llm_chain.generate([
        {"text": "I love AI"},
        {"text": "I love the ocean"},
    ])

for g in response.generations:
    print(g[0].text)
```

Note that I am using openAI in Azure,
I also tried this code and it's still giving me the same error

```
deployment_name = "my-deployment-name"
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
llm = AzureOpenAI(deployment_name=deployment_name )
print(llm)
llm("Tell me a joke")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I finally was able to fix it by creating an extension of AzureOpenai class and nullifying those arguments. Code that works is below:

```
from langchain.llms import AzureOpenAI
from typing import List
class NewAzureOpenAI(AzureOpenAI):
    stop: List[str] = None
    @property
    def _invocation_params(self):
        params = super()._invocation_params
        # fix InvalidRequestError: logprobs, best_of and echo parameters are not available on gpt-35-turbo model.
        params.pop('logprobs', None)
        params.pop('best_of', None)
        params.pop('echo', None)
        #params['stop'] = self.stop
        return params
    
llm = NewAzureOpenAI(deployment_name=deployment_name,temperature=0.9)
llm("Tell me a joke")
```

The answer was actually found in [this link](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/1591) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ChatOpenAI` instead of `OpenAI` (and `model_name` instead of `engine`) works for me on `langchain==0.0.127`.
There is [this warning on langchain's `OpenAI` code](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/1c03205cc225ca62c4687344deee8525f6c5adb3/langchain/llms/openai.py#L168-L173)

```py
        if model_name.startswith("gpt-3.5-turbo") or model_name.startswith("gpt-4"):
            warnings.warn(
                "You are trying to use a chat model. This way of initializing it is "
                "no longer supported. Instead, please use: "
                "`from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI`"
            )
```

This code is working for me:

```py
import os
from langchain.chains.llm import LLMChain
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", openai_api_key=os.environ['OPENAI_KEY'])

template = """
You are a helpful assistant that translates English to French. Translate this sentence from English to French: {text}
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["text"], template=template)
llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
response = llm_chain.generate([
        {"text": "I love AI"},
        {"text": "I love the ocean"},
    ])

for g in response.generations:
    print(g[0].text)
```

Comment: Tried that and it gave me this error: InvalidRequestError: Must provide an 'engine' or 'deployment_id' parameter to create a <class 'openai.api_resources.chat_completion.ChatCompletion'>..

Comment: Your error message mentions `ChatCompletion` as opposed to `ChatOpenAI`, could you be using the wrong class? If not, what version of langchain are you using?

Edit: I didn't realize the `ChatCompletion` came from the openai package. Maybe try `pip install -U openai`

Comment: If you're using azure, this might also be happening to you https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/318

Comment: I am using Azure. is there anyway to make langchain work with azure?

Comment: I tried AzureOpenAI as well and it's giving me the same error (edited the post above with that code too)

Comment: The comments on the GitHub issue I linked have a couple of suggestions. Unfortunately I don't have experience with Azure models.